# moment.js вывод даты

Tags: javascript, дата, momentjs

Здравствуйте.

Использую библиотеку `moment.js`. Пытаюсь вывести разницу во времени в нужном формате. И вот никак не могу понять как объединить, одно с другим. На данный момент имею:

```
moment.lang('ru');
// результат будет: 2016-03-30 23:59:57
$('.block').html(moment('2016-03-30 23:59:57').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
// результат будет: месяц назад
$('.block').html(moment('2016-03-30 23:59:57').fromNow());
```

Пытаюсь вывести что-то в этом роде `0000-00-27 06:58:52` - здесь количество времени сколько прошло, с момента даты указанной в .moment(...). Проще говоря, необходимо показать в таком формате: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` разницу во времени.

Что необходимо сделать, чтоб реализовать вывод даты в нужном формате?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var moment = require('moment');
moment.locale('ru');

var now = moment();
var event = moment('2016-03-30 23:59:57');

console.log('Сегодня: ' + now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
console.log('Дата события: ' + event.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
console.log('Событие произошло ' + event.fromNow());
console.log('Разница во времени: ' + now.subtract(event.toObject()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

Comment: `require()` убрал, без него работает отлично. Спасибо!

Comment: Ага. require - это для NodeJS :)